# How can I export the results into Latex format

Tags: html, r, latex, export

I am using table1 command, I want to get the following results:

```
library(formattable)
library(table1)
library(xtable)

table1::table1(~Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length | Species, data = iris,output="latex")
```

The results shown in viewer section, how can I get the latex code for the output?

if not, is there is a way to convert between html and latex in R?

Comment: I tried, but I couldn't get the latex code

Comment: The package description says "Tables of Descriptive Statistics in HTML." I don't think it does latex. it just seems to produce HTML.